typescript check only local library (*.d.ts) files
I'm working on migrating a project that currently uses JSDoc type hints and JavaScript (slowly) to TypeScript. Right now, I have a lot of manual type definitions in types/*.d.ts. I would like TypeScript to check those.
However, I also have a problem that vitest is failing to find its node dependencies. I've been able to work around that by setting skipLibCheck: true in tsconfig.json; however, AFAICT, it then skips checking the local "lib" files, too (I see errors in the IDE which aren't reported in typescript --build).
Is there a way to tell it to check my local *.d.ts files, but not the ones in node_modules?
I also tried setting skipDefaultLibCheck: true, but that doesn't fix the original problem.

You might have a few options.
In your tsconfig.json file you can add:
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
]

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#exclude
you also can try adding // @ts-nocheck at the top of any file you are having problems with.
Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#-ts-nocheck-in-typescript-files

Thanks, but I already had "node_modules" in exclude. Have also tried **/node_modules/**/* and various other combinations. Can't do @ts-nocheck as it's a 3rd-party package. I think I need a way to explicitly check *.d.ts even when skipLibCheck is true.
